# What is the quickest way to convert XML file to JSON file in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml, file, file-writing

I currently have a bunch of XML files(each are 16kb in size) that need to be converted into JSON and then written to new files. I have a working implementation but it's very slow.

What I'm doing is grabbing each file in the directory, converting the XML data to a string, creating a JSON object of that String with org.json, then using FileWriter to write it to a file

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public class TestConvert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final File xmlFolder = new File("C:\\files\\xml_files");
        final File jsonFolder = new File("C:\\files\\json_files");

        for(File fileEntry: xmlFolder.listFiles()){
            try {
                String xml = new String(Files.readAllBytes(fileEntry.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);

                String completeDir = jsonFolder + "\\" + FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileEntry.getName()) + ".json";

                FileWriter file = new FileWriter(completeDir);
                obj.write(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does work, however I'm currently testing this with ~370k XML files, and the running time is a shade over 45 minutes. This seems excessive, and I'd really like to cut down the length of time it takes to complete this.

Comment: You could use multi-threading to complete the process in even lesser time. Spawn numbers of threads and give each thread a number of xml files.

Comment: How big are your XML files?  How many elements and depth?  This could be an amazingly fast time for all we know!

Comment: That's a good point, Jamie. Thank you. Each file size is 16kb. I believe it goes to a depth of 10 or 11.

Comment: Have you considered xslt?

Comment: don't know if it will be faster or not, but give jackson library a try, this, and use a threadpool and split different files across different threads.

Comment: Is there a specific way that I can have threads grab different XML files and write new ones without explicitly telling them? Say if I didn't know any of the file names or how many files there were, could it still be done? Or would I need to set that process up manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

And Java file:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Main {

    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><test attrib=\"moretest\">Turn this to JSON</test>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have tried using a BufferedOutputStream, or the following.
I used Files.list, as the tradition `File.listFiles` is slow for large directories.

```
    final Path xmlFolder = Paths.get("C:\\files\\xml_files");
    final Path jsonFolder = xmlFolder.resolveSibling("json_files");

    Files.list(xmlFolder)
        .forEach(path -> {
        try {
            String xml = new String(Files.readAllBytes(fileEntry.toPath()),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            // 1
            final int initialXmlSize = 320 * 1024;
            JSONObject obj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
            StringWriter xmlOut = new StringWriter(initialXmlSize);
            obj.write(xmlOut);
            String xml = xmlOut.toString();
            // 2

            String jsonFileName = path.getFileName().toString().replaceFirst("\\.[^\\.]+$",
                "") + ".json";
            Path xmlPath = jsonFolder.resolve(jsonFileName);
            Files.write(xmlPath, xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File " + path);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The code between `// 1` and `// 2` could be optimized further to only use strings, no DOM objects (XM, JSON). **XSLT** would be one solution (though faster?).

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`. I am the maintainer of the project.